# Windows Phone 7 EMULATOR Crash Dump or Debugging

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to debug a default application like Internet Explorer on WP7 Emulator. Is there a way to attach it to debugger ? Or how can I access the crash dumps when a crash occurs on WP7 Emulator??

Answer (score 5):

You cannot debug system applications with the default toolset available from Microsoft. You can, however, keep track of events that occur in the emulator by enabling the verbose mode (aka to show the console).

To do this, open `regedit` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\XDE` (for 64bit systems) or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\XDE` (for 32bit systems) and create a new **DWORD** key, named `EnableConsole`. Set its value to **0x00000001 (1)**.

Now, every time the emulator starts, there will be a console window that will show you the system events that are going on.

Comment: Hi Dennis Thanks for your reply and tip.. Its not possible to debug on emulator but is it possible to debug system applications on a real device??

Comment: Also, this is not possible with the default toolset.