# Handle windows phone 7 app crash

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I create a dump of an application on widows phone , in case it crashes , so I cad debug it later.
I know there is App.UnhandledException event , but I don't know how to dump the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [Little Watson](http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/10/02/wp7-littlewatson-extended-error-reporting-to-http-endpoint/), part of the [NorthernLights WP7 Toolkit](http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/11/07/wp7-northern-lights-wp7-toolkit-v0-0-1/).  But Bugsense looks interesting and I'm going to have to check it out.  +1

Update: the telerik RadDiagnstic control works great too.

Answer (score 2):

Why even bother doing this yourself? There are tools like [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/) out there that do this perfectly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these answers on previous questions also about app crashes and dumps can help you further:

- [Application crash when using 3G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977006/application-crash-when-using-3g/8977617#8977617)
- [Windows Phone 7 EMULATOR Crash Dump or Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212961/windows-phone-7-emulator-crash-dump-or-debugging/5213257#5213257)